# How many 1.5V batteries can I charge simultaneously in series?

Tags: batteries, charger

I'm wondering if there is a limit in terms of how many batteries can I can charge simultaneously ?

I would like to charge 30 batteries at the same time, they will all be in series.

Will it work ?

Comment: If i told you that the limit is 25 batteries in series, would you believe that? Would you ask **why**? Yep, nasty questions. We like to encourage *thinking* here instead of just answering yes/no. When we **think** we might learn something :-) Think about that the limit of how many batteries isn't a theoretical limit but a practical one. Suppose you try to charge 100 batteries in series but there's **one** battery not making a good contact. What would happen?

Comment: Yes you're probably right. If only one doesn't make contact, no battery at all we'll charge. But the batteries will be on a PCB which i wouldn't have any problem about contact reliability.
But I guess with that much batteries I might have some unbalanced issues ?

Comment: *But I guess with that much batteries I might have some unbalanced issues ?* Even with 2 batteries there can be imbalance issues. With more batteries the possibilities for imbalances increases. What kind of batteries are we talking about (what chemistry) ? How fast do you want to charge them? Fast charging is not an option when charging in series due to imbalances resulting in overcharging and damaging the batteries.

Comment: 30 x 1.5 V = 45 V, at what current? Is the current small enough not to burn the contacts out when contact is not good. You say it is on a PCB but that is no guarantee for good contact everywhere. There might be dirt/oxidation on the battery itself.

Comment: I will use NiMH batterie in AAA which they'll have about 1000mAh.
How fast this isn't important it could take days. And the current I don't know exactly now but I think between 500mA and 1A.

Comment: *And the current I don't know exactly now but I thinks between 500mA and 1A.* You writing that leads me to recommend that you do some research on NiMh battery charging: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_metal_hydride  You really should **not** be charging 1000 mAh NiMh batteries with 500 mA to 1 A. You should use less than 100 mA.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to charge more than one NiMH at a time. NiMH will be destroyed if there is a polarity reversal. Also, end of charge detection is a problem with NiMH, so building a charger from scratch is a lot of work.

Comment: To charge batteries in series they need to have the same level of charge to begin with otherwise one will be overcharged before the other is fully charged.

Comment: I don't know of any 1.5V rechargeable chemistries.... Please don't try to recharge alkaline batteries.

Answer (score 1):

The Voltage of any N cells in series connected charge current will rise =CdV/dt and thus the voltage of the weakest battery C[kF] will reach 100% SoC before the rest.

Given that it is common for bulk e-Caps to have 20% tolerance, I would expect no less unless perfectly matched in  the same batch and binned, then *maybe* <0.1%.

The problem is even if they start perfectly balanced with 0% mismatch, after a few charge cycles, the aging rate will vary due to temperature differences of the pack. This starts an acceleration rate of imbalanced by reason that either you overcharge the weakest cell and thus accelerate the aging rate or are properly undercharged by X% leaving the weakest at 100%.

This results in an Nth order equation where aging rate starts very slow after each charge cycle then accelerates by the Nth magnitude resulting in premature cell death depending N and amount of time in an over or under charge condition.

Hence , there is a practical limit improved by a BMS design.